# What is, exactly, an opinion?

Tags: discussion, subjective

["Real questions have answers, not ideas, items or opinions"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/) is the *only* rule I've been looking at when moderating questions accused of being subjective. However, it turns out "opinion" isn't that clear cut of a term.

(How surprising: there is no objective definition of what belongs to the realm of subjectivity.)

1. What is an opinion?
2. What makes it different from an answer?
3. Can a subjective question have answers and not opinions?

Hint: if your answer to point 3 is "no" then you're probably on the wrong path.

Comment: That question reminds me of dating my now-girlfriend.  6 months and at least 1000 hours of discussion time just on point 1.  Also on proving the comment. Mathematically, at that.  Once I did that, she agreed to go out with me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**tl;dr**: An opinion is not *falsifiable* (e.g. "I like X better than Y"). An answer is (e.g. "X is better than Y").

---

The term "opinion" is an umbrella that contains two sort of statements:

- Analysis
- Preference

I think this is really what Robert Cartaino was touching on in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). An opinion can be grounded in facts, explaining the how and the why, a thoughtful analysis that weigh each factor carefully - or it can be a mere statement of one's tastes.

The best display of the difference I can remember  of right now is Roger Ebert's [I'm a proud Brainiac](http://blogs.suntimes.com/ebert/2009/07/i_am_a_brainiac.html) blog post, where he does show there are two kinds of opinions:

> So let's focus on those who seriously believe "Transformers" is one of the year's best films. Are these people wrong? Yes. They are wrong. I am fond of the story I tell about Gene Siskel. When a so-called film critic defended a questionable review by saying, "after all, it's opinion," Gene told him: "There is a point when a personal opinion shades off into an error of fact. When you say 'The Valachi Papers' is a better film than 'The Godfather,' you are wrong."

Ebert makes a distinction between a good film and enjoying a film. The former requires an analysis of the *craft* behind the film; the latter is a summary of *your own personal experience*.

An analysis of the craft behind the film can be wrong. There is certainly room for healthy and reasonable differences of opinions, **but past a certain point you're just flat out wrong.** There are some films which are simply masterfully executed and other films which certainly are amateurish. You can say that of your own personal preferences. It's your preferences. **Preferences can't be wrong.** And *that* is where the problem lies. **It's an answer that can't be wrong.**

I think that's the litmus test for an helpful subjective answer: **while the answer is spot on, it could have been wrong, if the author had a poor grasp of the subject.**

Opinions can make very good answers, if they care thoughtful analysises. Strategies often are subjective in nature, yet are extremely useful answers. The answer to [How do I know when it's time to push?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16829/how-do-i-know-when-its-time-to-push) is subjective in nature, but it can also be wrong. Pushing at level 1 is a very bad idea.

Comment: this is an amazingly great answer

Comment: I fully agree with your thought process; I would also submit that what you're calling a good "opinion" answer is in fact an analysis, or an evaluation, not simply an opinion. If the opinion is the *entire* answer (in reference to the now-widespread "real questions have answers, not [...] opinions") then it will *ipso facto* be devoid of any pertinent facts or logic.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't cite hard data or reference articles to support what you wrote ... it's probably an opinion.

Comment: I think that here on gaming, a *lot* of answers are lessons learned from personal experience. Then again, these probably appear in questions that are usually not problematic.

Comment: @oak well if you want my *honest* opinion, this site should not work at all on our engine. That it does even a little is a testament to the strength of the community, but I still have reservations about it personally.. and I'm saying that as a gamer myself.

Comment: @Oak there's a difference between verifiable in *practice* and verifiable in *principle*. Good, useful answers on Gaming.SE are verifiable in principle: play the game and if the strategy works, it's right. To that end, answers on Gaming.SE aren't writing the Great American Novel: there will have been many people who have done it, verified it, and documented it elsewhere on the web. So answers should always be verifiable in practice as well: if one can't find *any* external sources verifying an answer, it's either an untested opinion/guess/speculation or one hasn't looked hard enough.